Google Chrome NativeMessaging not working when using Selenium
When i start a Selenium Test with added Chrome Extension .crx, the browser opens with the installed extension. The ID of the extension is correct. However, I always get 'Native Messaging Host not found'.

Used versions:

OS: Ubuntu  22.04.4 LTS
Google Chrome (for testing) and chromedriver: 124.0
Selenium: 4.22.0


When I open the browser without selenium NativeMessaging is working
Java code looks like:

ChromeOptions cOpt = new ChromeOptions();
cOpt.setBinary("/path/to/google-chrome-for-testing");
File extension = new File("/path/to/extension.crx");
cOpt.addExtensions(Arrays.asList(extension));
return new ChromeDriver(cOpt);


The Native Messaging host file is located in ~/.config/google-chrome-for-testing/NativeMessagingHosts

The name and id in the .json file is correct


For me it looks like a browser started with selenium is looking at another location for the NativeMessagingHosts file.

So what helps was setting the user-data-dir to the google-chrome-for-testing directory
cOpt.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/path/to/home/user/.config/google-chrome-for-testing")

So everytime the same profile is used.
